# Where to place an Include for it to be available for the entire Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, rubygems

I want to use the `term-ansicolor` gem to help me out developing and debugging.

Simply requiring it in the Gemfile isn't enough as somewhere in the app, `include Term::ANSIColor` must show up.

I created a `config/initializers/colors.rb` and it worked as intended, but an initializer doesn't seem like the right place for it.

Where is the ideal place for this include statement?

I'm running rails version 4.2, if it makes any difference.

Comment: hmm, high level includes could go in application.rb

Comment: but thinking about it - an intializer is actually a good place for it.

Comment: @TarynEast So you're saying the 45 minutes I've wasted on #rubyonrails listening to dudes pontificating on what I'm doing wrong were in fact wasted and initializers is a good place to put the include? May as well get the points for the answer :(

Comment: Sure thing, if you like :) Sorry you had to waste so much time on pontificators... people do like to share their opinions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

high level includes could go in application.rb but an intitializer is a good enough place to put stuff like this.